# StackNavigator: Not able to change font color for the header title

Tags: react-native, react-navigation

I am trying to change the color of the font for the title from black to white. Not able to do it. I have the following in the code:

```
navigationOptions: {
  title: 'PRACTICIA',
  headerLeft: null,
  headerStyle: {
    backgroundColor: '#33ACDE',
    color: 'white'
    }
  }
}
```

and i get the following result (black).

[image]

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Style defined in `headerStyle` will be applied to the header `<View />`.

To apply style to the title, you must use `headerTitleStyle` as described in the [StackNavigator documentation](https://reactnavigation.org/docs/navigators/stack#headerTitleStyle).

```
navigationOptions: {
  title: 'PRACTICIA',
  headerLeft: null,
  headerStyle: {
    backgroundColor: '#33ACDE'
  },
  headerTitleStyle: {
    color: 'white'
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Within your **navigation.js file**, just add **headerTitleStyle ** and then add **color of your choice**. Follow the code snippet for your reference:

```
<Stack.Navigator 
       screenOptions={{
            headerTitleStyle : {
              color: 'white'
            }
       }} >
```